# In SQL can I return a tables with a varying number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a somewhat more complicated scenario, but I think it should be possible.

I have a large SPROC whose result is a set of characteristics for a set of persons.

So the Table would look something like this:

```
Property |	 Client1 	 Client 2	 Client3
-----------------------------------------------------------
Sex      |	 M       	 F      	  M
Age      |	 67      	 56     	  67
Income   |	 Low     	 Mid    	  Low
```

It's built using cursors, iterating over different datasets.

The problem I am facing is that there is a varying number of Clients and Properties, so an equally valid result over different input sets might be:

```
Property |	 Client1 	 Client 2
-------------------------------------------
Sex      |	 M       	 F   
Age      |	 67      	 56  
Weight   |	 122     	 122
```

The different number of properties is easy, those are just extra rows.

My problem is that I need to declare a temporary table with a varying number of columns.

There could be 2 clients or 100. Every client in guaranteed to have every property ultimately listed.

What SQL structure would statisfy this and how can I declare it and insert things into it?

I can't just flip the columns and rows either because there is a variable number of each.

Comment: Your ordering of rows and columns seems transposed from what seems logical and usual. Once transposed, this is simply a case of a select that happens to return a different number of columns, which happens...well, every time you use a select. Is the stored proc the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should consider normalizing your design like so:

```
Create Table ClientAttributes
(
    ClientId ....
    , Sex Char(1)...
    , Age int...
    , Income...
)
```

Second, the SQL language in general is not geared for dynamic column generation. To achieve this, you have to build the SQL statement at runtime (a.k.a. dynamic SQL) as a string. It is best to do this in the middle-tier or a reporting engine rather than in T-SQL.

Third, an infinitely flexible design where you have no idea as to the number or types of properties or instances isn't a design at all. Each table represents a collection of entities with known attributes. They are not wads of arbitrary data. The attributes (columns) need to be known at design time or you risk a Cthulhu design where nothing but chaos reins.

Will Hughes' suggestion is to use an Entity-Attribute-Value design (a.k.a. EAV). It takes a *tremendous* amount of discipline to do an EAV correctly. It only works if it is treated solely as a wad of data. I.e., no developer can ever filter on any specific attribute (i.e. hard code a query looking for a specific attribute name), ever calculate on the values and you will never be able to ensure consistency amongst specific values. If you can maintain that discipline, then an arbitrary wad of data as a *limited* portion to a larger design can work. However, once you decide to hard code a query looking for a specific attribute you have gone down the dark path and forever will it dominate your destiny. As the database grows, the performance will degrade significantly. You will have no data integrity (e.g. you have two attributes called "Age" and "Client Age" with some values being integers and others being text). EAVs can be a nightmare to maintain. It is far better for maintenance, reporting, querying etc. to have a normalized design.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like you're using Pivoting on the server*.

While you CAN do this, it's going to be pretty awkward to deal with - and I don't know of any ORM that will work that well for you (if you go down that path).

Instead of Pivoting, how about arranging it more like(*2):

```
Client  |  Property  |  Value 
------------------------------
Client 1|  Sex       | M 
Client 1|  Age       | 67
```

This way you can still do that per-Client pivoting in your application for display purposes.

(* FWIW: You do know SQL Server 2005+ has [PIVOT Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), right? To save you using cursors.)

(*2 This is just a *possible* approach. It's hacky, and Thomas's recommendation to normalise your schema is a much better and (likely) more efficient option.)

Comment: Ew...EAV. You might also mention or link to some of the pitfalls to an EAV.

Comment: Looks like you've done a pretty good job of explaining why it's a bad idea :)